# c# how to rotate video stream inside a picturebox

Tags: c#, video, rotation, television, tuner

I have a livestream coming in from a TV Tuner into a picturebox. How do I rotate the video feed if I wanted to create a button to do that? Or change its opacity etc.

Any recommended lbiraries to do this? picturebox is pathetically limited

Comment: are you using winforms of WPF ?

Comment: Well seeing you dont reply, if you are using winforms, switch to WPF, it has all those niftly properties built in.